# Algorithm for root system of Coxeter group generated by permutations

Tags: gr.group-theory, algorithms, coxeter-groups, computational-group-theory

Suppose we are given a group $G$ in terms of generators $t_1, ..., t_n$ which are order 2 in $S_m$ (however we don't assume anything other than that these elements generate $G$ and have order 2). What is the most efficient way to determine:

1. If $G$ is abstractly isomorphic to a Coxeter group
2. Assuming yes, a Coxeter system for $G$
3. Assuming no, a presentation of $G$ as a quotient of a Coxeter group

Comment: I don't get your question exactly: the $t_i$ having order 2 does not make them transpositions necessarily (viewed inside $S_m$ at least); and since they are not simple transpositions it's not clear that $(G,\{t_1,\ldots,t_n\})$ is in fact a Coxeter system. (Note that the abstract group structure of $G$ is not enough to necessarily recover its structure as a Coxeter group, in particular, its root system.)

Comment: I definitely don't want to assume that $(G, {t_1,...,t_n})$ is a Coxeter system, but if I understand correctly, $G$ should have some generators that form a Coxeter system. My question is how to find one choice of such generators.

Comment: Why should it have generators like that? In general a group generated by involutions is just a quotient of a Coxeter group.

Comment: You are right, I've made a mistake. Should I edit the question to ask for a presentation as a quotient of a Coxeter group? Is there a standard form for this? If there is no reasonable way to amend the question I can accept your comment if you post as an answer.

Comment: It'd be better for you to edit the question to reflect what you want to ask (or if you realize your question doesn't make sense, just delete it).

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the question so hopefully there are no errors now. If it still doesn't make sense I'll probably just delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a theoretical answer (as opposed to an algorithmic answer) found in Björner and Brenti's "Combinatorics of Coxeter groups", Section 1.5.  (They seem to credit it to Matsumoto.)  Their Theorem 1.5.1:

Suppose $W$ is a group generated by a subset $S$ consisting of elements of order $2$.  Then TFAE:

1. $(W,S)$ is a Coxeter system (i.e. $S$ generates $W$ as a Coxeter group)
2. $(W,S)$ has the Exchange Property.
3. $(W,S)$ has the Deletion Property.

These are properties written in terms of reduced words.

To talk about an actual algorithm, we need a precise meaning to the assumption that "we are given a group $G$ in terms of generators $t_1,\ldots,t_n$".  The only reasonable interpretation I'm finding for that is that we have an oracle that tells you whether two words in the generators stand for the same element.

In principle, you could design a "partial" algorithm, by checking Exchange or Deletion.  But if your group is infinite, it might run forever, and you would never know whether your algorithm is about to come up with a counterexample to Exchange or Deletion.

EDIT:  Now that I have noticed that the question specifies that all this takes place inside some symmetric group $S_m$:  The group $G$ is finite, so there are finitely many reduced words, and the Exchange Property can be checked in finite time.

Comment: I was almost finished with this answer, when I noticed the crucial piece of information in the question:  $t_1,\ldots,t_n$ are assumed to be elements of order 2 in $S_m$, which I assume is the symmetric group.  So this answer addresses a more general situation.  But I think it's worth pointing out, so I'm keeping it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is what the questioner means, so this is not really an answer.  But it's worth mentioning and it's too long for a comment.

If we know that $t_1,\ldots,t_n$ are transpositions, then $G$ is a "reflection subgroup" of $S_m$ (a subgroup generated by reflections).  Then a theorem of Deodhar ("A note on subgroups generated by reflections in Coxeter groups") and Dyer ("Reflection subgroups of Coxeter systems") tells us that $G$ is a Coxeter group.  They also give a recipe for finding a simple system:  Find all transpositions in $G$ and find the corresponding positive roots.  Out of all these positive roots, find the unique minimal subset such that all positive roots are in the nonnegative span of the subset.  The transpositions for that subset are the simple system.

In this case, $G$ will be a product of symmetric groups.

Comment: In the comments I pointed out that in the question the $t_i$ are not necessarily assumed to be transpositions, which makes the question weird/unnatural, and the OP seemed to agree. So I think they really don't want to assume that the $t_i$ are transpositions.

Comment: Btw, regarding your last sentence: if the $t_i$ really are transpositions, it should be easy to see which product of symmetric groups we get if we just draw the "graph" of the transpositions- then the connected components of this graph tells us the product.

Comment: @SamHopkins:  I agree that this is not what the OP wants.  It just seemed worth mentioning, because the Dyer/Deodhar result is very important in more general situations.

Comment: @SamHopkins: I don't think the question is weird or unnatural.  Consider asking the OP's 3 questions for *any* finite group generated by elements of order 2.  To me that seems very natural.  But then, any finite group is a subgroup of some finite symmetric group, so the OP's question is the same.  And the way that the OP phrases it is nice for actual computations.  If we are given the elements as permutations, we can actually compute.

Comment: Fair enough, that makes sense!